# Recorder for Oracle form(Applets) Actions or Oracle JVM Hook

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-ebs

I making recorder which record actions on Oracle EBS forms, for this i hook JVM which is open by oracle applet(form) using Java instrumentation.

I list the virtual machines and hook that machine which name contains "sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain"

Is this best approach for recording oracle form actions or some other approach which is best and you can suggest?

Thanks, in advance.